# How to securely have many to many users on virtual hosts

Tags: php, linux, nginx, permissions, sshd

I currently setup a single user on my virtual host like this:

```
sudo useradd -d /website/ -m user -s /usr/bin/rssh

sudo chown root:root /website/ -R #Don't get why I need this part but doesn't work without! 
sudo chmod 755 /website/
sudo chown -R user:www-data /website/public_html
sudo chmod 755 /website/public_html
```

This works for `user` to add and edit folders and files within `/website/public_html`.

I now want to be able to add other users with the ability to add and edit folders and files within `/website/public_html`. The issue with this, is that if I get into using groups and add users to the group `www-data` and change the chmod to 775 the users will then be able to edit other virtual hosts websites for example `/website2/public_html`.

All users (as you can see above) can only access the server through sftp (`-s /usr/bin/rssh`). Users are also locked to their home directories with the help of settings from `sshd_config`†. As of that I suppose I could add all the users to the same group (`www-data`) and `chmod 775` the directory or is that not safe **?**

For example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/312999/is-it-safe-to-chmod-775-664-with-owner-www-datawww-data) someone mentions that giving the virtual hosts `775` permissions may allow for users to insert php scripts that could delete everything. But without it being `775` this also does not allow for php to create files.

†:

```
Match user user
        ChrootDirectory /website/
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        GatewayPorts no
        X11Forwarding no
```

Comment: you need to add permissions for users of the same group sudo chmod -R 775 to the public_html or www folder.

Comment: But as I said I have many virtual hosts so this will lead to other people having access to other sites!

Comment: How about creating a new group for each virtual host, adding www-data and other granted users to that, and doing chown for that group?

Comment: @Ahmad thanks that worked!!

Comment: @Maximilian: Your welcome! Please mark my answer as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new group for each virtual host and add www-data and other granted users to this. Then set that group as the owner of your files (chown). With specifying an appropriate permission (like 775) you will be there.